# Get just the test data for a spec'd function

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Is there a way for me to generate just the test data for a function previously spec'd with `fdef`? In other words I would like to have the functionality of `check` but up to just generating a number of argument sets for me, not running the function and checking the outputs are correct.

Alternatively, if it's possible to lookup the argument (`:args`) spec of a function then this would achieve the same goal as I could then make a generator from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to define your args spec separately so you can use it in the `fspec` and easily get it later for individual generation.

```
(defn foo [x] (inc x))
(s/def ::foo-args (s/cat :x number?))
(s/fdef foo :args ::foo-args)
(gen/sample (s/gen ::foo-args))
=> ((2.0) (-1.5) (0) (1) (1.0) (-1) (1.5) (0.5) (-5.0) (-7))
```

If you don't have direct access to the original `:args` spec, here's a clunky way to recreate it from the `fspec`:

```
(s/fdef foo :args (s/cat :x number?))
(def foo-args-spec
  (eval (->> (s/get-spec `foo)
             (s/form) ;; get original fspec form
             (rest) ;; discard fspec symbol
             (apply hash-map) ;; put fspec kwargs into map
             (:args))))
(gen/sample (s/gen foo-args-spec))
=> ((0.5) (-3.0) (-1.5) (2) (-1) (-5) (-1.75) (-2) (-13) (2.3828125))
```